# Inheritance resulting null value in the subclass

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

It works fine when I directly use the superclass, but when I trying to print out the value using the subclass it returns a null value.
I created 2 classes for display and recording purposes, suppose the "room" read and stores the value that going to be recorded into the text file after user make their choices while the "roomView" is used to display the normal input that the user going to read.
I have tried putting setRoomID and getRoomID into the subclass, it worked but I think if I put all the getter and setter into the subclass the inheritance would be meaningless.
Below is my superclass:

```
public class Room {

    private String roomID;
    private String roomTypeID;
    private Integer floor;
    private String roomStatus;

    //Setter
    public void setRoomID(String roomID) {
        this.roomID = roomID;
    }

    public void setRoomType(String roomTypeID) {
        this.roomTypeID = roomTypeID;
    }

    public void setFloor(Integer floor) {
        this.floor = floor;
    }

    public void setRoomStatus(String roomStatus) {
        this.roomStatus = roomStatus;
    }

    //Getter
    public String getRoomID() {
        return this.roomID;
    }

    public String getRoomType() {
        return this.roomTypeID;
    }

    public Integer getFloor() {
        return this.floor;
    }

    public String getRoomStatus() {
        return this.roomStatus;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return roomID + " " + roomTypeID + " " + floor + " " + roomStatus;
    }
}
```

Below is my subclass:

```
public class RoomFrontEnd extends Room {

    private String roomID;
    private String roomType;
    private Integer floor;
    private String roomStatus;

    public void setRoomTypeID(Integer roomTypeID) {
        if (roomTypeID.equals("RT1")) {
            this.roomType = "Single Room";
        } else if (roomTypeID.equals("RT2")) {
            this.roomType = "Double Room";
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getRoomTypeID() {
        return this.roomType;
    }

    public void setRoomStatus(String roomStatus) {
        if (roomStatus.equals("1")) {
            this.roomStatus = "Available";
        } else if (roomStatus.equals("0")) {
            this.roomStatus = "Not Available";
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getRoomStatus() {
        return this.roomStatus;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return roomID + " " + roomType + " Floor " + floor + " " + roomStatus;
    }
}
```

And below my test driver:

```
public class Test3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Room[] room = new Room[72];
        RoomFrontEnd[] roomView = new RoomFrontEnd[72];
        Integer i = 0;
        try {
            File RoomTxt = new File("Room.txt");
            Scanner read = new Scanner(RoomTxt);
            while (read.hasNextLine()) {
                room[i] = new Room();
                room[i].setRoomID(read.next());
                room[i].setRoomTypeID(read.next());
                room[i].setFloor(read.nextInt());
                room[i].setRoomStatus(read.next());
                i++;
            }
            read.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for (i = 0; i < 72; i++) {
            roomView[i] = new RoomFrontEnd();
            roomView[i].setRoomID(room[i].getRoomID());
            roomView[i].setRoomTypeID(room[i].getRoomTypeID());
            roomView[i].setFloor(room[i].getFloor());
            roomView[i].setRoomStatus(room[i].getRoomStatus());
        }

        for (i = 0; i < 72; i++) {
            System.out.println(roomView[i].toString());
        }
    }
}
```

The output I get when running test driver:

```
null null Floor null Available
null null Floor null Not Available
null null Floor null Not Available
null null Floor null Available
null null Floor null Available
null null Floor null Not Available
null null Floor null Available
null null Floor null Available
null null Floor null Not Available
null null Floor null Available
null null Floor null Not Available
null null Floor null Available
null null Floor null Available
null null Floor null Available
null null Floor null Not Available
null null Floor null Available
null null Floor null Not Available
null null Floor null Not Available
null null Floor null Not Available
null null Floor null Not Available
null null Floor null Not Available
null null Floor null Not Available
null null Floor null Not Available
null null Floor null Not Available
null null Floor null Available
null null Floor null Available
null null Floor null Available
null null Floor null Available
null null Floor null Not Available
null null Floor null Available
null null Floor null Not Available
null null Floor null Not Available
null null Floor null Not Available
null null Floor null Available
null null Floor null Not Available
null null Floor null Not Available
null null Floor null Available
null null Floor null Available
null null Floor null Not Available
null null Floor null Not Available
null null Floor null Not Available
null null Floor null Available
null null Floor null Not Available
null null Floor null Available
null null Floor null Not Available
null null Floor null Available
null null Floor null Available
null null Floor null Available
null null Floor null Not Available
null null Floor null Not Available
null null Floor null Not Available
null null Floor null Available
null null Floor null Not Available
null null Floor null Not Available
null null Floor null Not Available
null null Floor null Available
null null Floor null Available
null null Floor null Available
null null Floor null Available
null null Floor null Available
null null Floor null Available
null null Floor null Not Available
null null Floor null Not Available
null null Floor null Available
null null Floor null Available
null null Floor null Available
null null Floor null Available
null null Floor null Available
null null Floor null Available
null null Floor null Available
null null Floor null Available
null null Floor null Available
```

Comment: I forgotten to post the text file, here is it:
RS11 RT1 1 1
RD12 RT2 1 0
RS13 RT1 1 0
RD14 RT2 1 1
RS15 RT1 1 1
RD16 RT2 1 0
RS17 RT1 1 1
RD18 RT2 1 1
RS19 RT1 1 0
RS21 RT1 2 1
RD22 RT2 2 0
RS23 RT1 2 1
RD24 RT2 2 1
RS25 RT1 2 1
RD26 RT2 2 0
RS27 RT1 2 1
RD28 RT2 2 0
RS29 RT1 2 0
RS31 RT1 3 0
RD32 RT2 3 0
RS33 RT1 3 0
RD34 RT2 3 0
RS35 RT1 3 0
RD36 RT2 3 0
RS37 RT1 3 1
RD38 RT2 3 1
RS39 RT1 3 1
RS41 RT1 4 1
RD42 RT2 4 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't redeclare the fields. But first: `RoomFrontEnd`  is a bizarro name and suggests you don't understand what subclassing is for. Think `Dog extends Mammal`, `Mammal extends Animal` - A subclass is like a more specific kind of what the inherited type already is. A `RoomFrontEnd` is nothing like a `Room`.

Once you've solved that problem, your `RoomFrontEnd` class has **2** completely unrelated fields, both called `roomID`. When you run `roomID = foo`, then you're setting one of the two.

Hence: Don't declare those fields *again* in `RoomFrontEnd`. RoomFrontEnd is a `Room` with additional stuff. Thus, you get all the fields `Room` already declared in your `RoomFrontEnd` automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The inheritance in this example is broken because the fields in the child class `RoomFrontEnd` duplicate and therefore hide the fields in the parent class `Room`.

So, when the setters set the values on different levels:

- `setRoomTypeID` and `setRoomStatus` are overridden in the **child** class and respective values are updated in `RoomFrontEnd`.
- `setRoomID` and `setFloor` are NOT overridden, and the values are set in the **parent** class fields thus keeping the values in child class `null`.

Then, `toString` is defined in both parent and child class and this method refers the fields on its own level.

Solution is quite simple:

- Remove declaration of the fields in the child class `RoomFrontEnd`